# Department Blog Implementation?

Tags: sharepoint-online, blog, best-practices

I have a SharePoint Online Site Collection (Using Classic Team Experience) and for each of the company's functional areas we want to implement a blog. Is the best way to do this to create a blog subsite for each Functional Area, or to have the users create pages in their functional area's subsite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's** preferred to create a blog subsite for each functional area for the following reasons:

- More Organized.
- "Out of the Box" Blog functionalities like

  - Manage comments.
  - Manage categories.
  - Manage posts.
  - Manage posts layout.
- Archiving feature for old blogs.
- Easy to manage permission.

> Creating pages in the same functional area subsites will add these
>   pages by default in **Site Pages** library that not suitable for blogs purpose. meanwhile, you will **lose** the main blog
>   functionalities and the above-mentioned features.